# Sortable with scriptaculous problems

Tags: scriptaculous

Im following a few tutorials to sort a list, but i can't get the DB to update. The drag drop side of things is working, also, i javascript alert() the serialize list onUpdate and the order is printed out as follows:

`images_list[]=20&images_list[]=19` etc...

So the sorting and dragging is working fine, i just cant get the database to update, this is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  Sortable.create("images_list", {
      onUpdate: function() {
          new Ajax.Request("processor.php", {
              method: "post",
              parameters: { data: Sortable.serialize("images_list") }
          });
      }
  });
```

processor.php code:

```
    //Connect to DB
require_once('connect.php');

parse_str($_POST['data']);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($images_list); $i++) {
    $id = $images_list[$i];
    mysql_query("UPDATE `images` SET `ranking` = '$i' WHERE `id` = '$id'");
}
```

Any ideas would be great, thankyou!

Comment: what have you tried to do to debug this? Have you checked in Firebug that the AJAX request is being made? have you outputted the SQL queries that are being generated to check they're valid?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have other tags in your elements for sorting. i would add tag: '':

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  Sortable.create("images_list", {
      onUpdate: function() {
          new Ajax.Request("processor.php", {
              method: "post",
              parameters: { data: Sortable.serialize("images_list") }
          });
      },
      tag: 'span'
  });
  </script>
```

Further i would check the path to your processor.php. I use:

```
new Ajax.Request("/youdir/processor.php", {
```

(Starting from DocumentRoot)