# Ajax.request not working

Tags: ajax, scriptaculous

I am sorting a list using scriptaculous, i can't get the ajax request part to work.

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  Sortable.create("images_list", {
      onUpdate: function() {
      var list = Sortable.serialize("images_list");
      alert(list);
          new Ajax.Request('processor.php', {
              method: 'post',
              parameters: { data: list }
          });

      }
  });
```

I Have alerted out the serialize string, this part is working fine:

```
images_list[]=18&images_list[]=19&images_list[]=21&images_list[]=22&images_list[]=20
```

So the sorting is working fine, however the data string doesn't seem to be available in the processor.php

```
<?php
```

//Connect to DB
require_once('connect.php');

parse_str($_POST['data']);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($images_list); $i++) {
    $id = $images_list[$i];
    mysql_query("UPDATE `images` SET `ranking` = '$i' WHERE `id` = '$id'");
}
?>

Any ideas why the data is not getting posted? I have tested to see if the processor.php page is actualy being invoked, and it is.

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sortable with scriptaculous problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057830/sortable-with-scriptaculous-problems)

Answer (score 0):

When method = 'post', you need to use "postBody" instead of "parameters" for having parameters posted to your server side script